# Material-ui: Routing tab using sharp(#) not slash(/)

Tags: reactjs, routes, tabs, react-router-dom

I am quite new to React and I am now developing a site using ReactJS and material-ui framework.

My problem is how to customize tab link urls like [this site](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#internaltx)

On this site, when I toggle tab button url is changed by adding `#(a-custom-tab-link)`.
Let's say I am on `xxx/yyy` url and if I toggle a tab with name zzz then url changes to `xxx/yyy#zzz`.

I have already made tabs using material-ui tabs component referencing [material-ui tabs docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs).
And I was able change tab url using `useRouteMatch` and code example is [here](https://b5nx1.csb.app/working).

Here are my problems.

1. How to change tab url not by adding `/` but adding `#` like [tab on this site](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#internaltx)
2. How to set first tab's router as same as it's parent's router so that display automatically.
   (I did this without considering router but if I consider changing router on tab toggling I can't do this)

Here is my code snippet at the moment.

```
  var TabHeaders = tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <Tab
      key={index.toString()}
      component={Link}
      to={`${match.url}/${tab.label}`}
      label={tab["label"]}
      {...a11yProps(tab["index"])}
    />
  ));

  var TabContents = tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <Route key={tab.id} exact path={`${match.url}/${tab.label}`}>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={tab["index"]}>
        {tab["children"]}
      </TabPanel>
    </Route>
  ));
```

and simple changing / to # is not working like the following.

```
  var TabHeaders = tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <Tab
      key={index.toString()}
      component={Link}
      to={`${match.url}#${tab.label}`}
      label={tab["label"]}
      {...a11yProps(tab["index"])}
    />
  ));

  var TabContents = tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <Route key={tab.id} exact path={`${match.url}#${tab.label}`}>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={tab["index"]}>
        {tab["children"]}
      </TabPanel>
    </Route>
  ));
```

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vldislav I'm not sure..https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/23/react-router-remove-trailing-slash-from-urls Can you try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to do the same for a while now, and I got it working (almost).  I triggered a URL fragment write to `window.location.hash` whenever the tabs got changed, in my `switchTabs` callback (`<Tabs onChange={switchTabs}>`), and used a `window.addEventListner('hashchange', () => setTab(window.location.hash.slice(1)))` event to update the tab state with a React hook.  All that worked fine, the <kbd>Back</kbd> and <kbd>Forward</kbd> buttons worked too.  The only issue was that the server ***does not see URL fragments*** (the hash (`#`) part of the URL), so if you try and access the page with a hash in your URL, it will initially be on the default, and the client would have to re-render as soon as the page loads.  Thats the part I got stuck on.  This probably isn't a problem if you're not using server-side rendering, you could just do

```js
const [currentTab, setTab] = useState(window.location.hash.slice(1) || 'myDefaultTab')
const switchTabs = (_, newTab) => {
  if (window.loaction.hash !== `#${newTab}`)
    window.location.hash = `#${newTab}`
  setTab(newTab)
}
window.addEventListner('hashchange', () => {
  setTab(window.location.hash.slice(1))
})
// ... then in your <Tabs> component
<Tabs value={currentTab} onChange={switchTabs}>
  // ...
</Tabs>
```

I decided instead to use a URL-style that is visible to the server, so that the initial `useState` can be set to the URL query parameters.
Insetead I used `?tab=myTabName`, this worked better when using server-side rendering.  In case you're interested:

```
// ... in render function: (initialTab is from the server query params)
const [currentTab, setTab] = useState(initialTab)
const switchTab = (_, newTab: string) => {
    setTab(newTab)
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
        window.history.pushState(null, null, `?tab=${newTab}`)
}
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        const newTab = params.get('tab')
        if (newTab) setTab(newTab)
    });
}
```

This works perfectly, navigation buttons (history), links, refreshing, etc.
This doesn't use `Router` or anything, and is quite basic, but then again, the `#` URL fragments are purely client-side.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Sammy. Seems like we got same solution. Here is [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-matsumoto-uyv6h?file=/src/Tabs.tsx).